# Problems with confirm on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, listview, onclientclick

This is very weird, i have an asp:ImageButton inside a list view and i want to confirm and action before i execute the method but i can't

then i created another imagebutton outside the list view and the confirm does work can u guys tell me why?

this doesn't work

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnEnabled" OnCommand="CommandExecution"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Desea eliminar el cliente ?');"  ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/Habilitar.png"
                Visible='<%# Eval("IsEnabled") %>' CommandName="ChangeStatus" ToolTip="Deshabilitar distribuidor"
                runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdClient") %>' />
```

this one does

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnConfirmacion3"  ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/Habilitar.png" runat="server" Text="Confirmacion 3" OnClientClick="return confirm('Desea eliminar el cliente ?');"   />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoPostback` to false. then create two hidden textboxes for command name and params. then place a hidden linkbutton in page. in onclientclick event of your image buttons after confirm place command name and params in hidden boxes and then call postback method of link button. then handle command in link button event handler.